# How to implement sorting

Tags: sails.js

How to implement sort method in sails.js?

When I run this code

```
try{
   let sort = req.param('name')
   let mysort = {}
   mysort.name = sort;
            
   let find = await dynamic.find().sort(mysort) //used to find All records from Database
   return res.status(200).json({
       "success":true,
       "find":find
    })
  }
```

in postman it gives an error.

I am expecting the database (records) to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the sort like this `name DESC` or `name ASC` from postman you need to pass `fieldName Order`

#### Code

```
try{
   let sort = req.param('name')
            
   let find = await dynamic.find().sort(sort) 
   return res.status(200).json({
       "success":true,
       "find":find
    })
  }
catch(error){
  return res.status(500).json({
       "success":false,
       "message":error
    })
}
```

#### Postman param

```
{{url}}?name="name ASC"
```

check [sails js](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/sort) doc for more information